# Fetch APIでUser-Agentを変更したGETリクエストを送る

Tags: javascript, python, ajax

Firefox39でFetch APIを使い、User-Agentを意図的に変更してGETリクエストを送信したいのですが、うまくできません。**サーバは127.0.0.1にあり、** 下記のようになっています。

```
import http.server

class handler(http.server.BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
        self.send_response(200, "OK")
        self.send_header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
        print(self.headers["User-Agent"])

server_address = ("", 8000)
httpd = http.server.HTTPServer(server_address, handler);
```

JavaScriptのコード

```
fetch("http://localhost:8000", {
    "mode": "cors",
    "headers": {
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.104 Safari/537.36" // ChromeのUser-Agent
    }
})
.then(() => console.log("Successed"))
.catch(() => console.log("Failed"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User-Agent をはじめとする一部ヘッダは変更することができません。

> [Headers - Web API Interfaces | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Headers)
>
> For security reasons, some headers can only be controller by the user agent. These headers include the [forbidden header names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Forbidden_header_name) and [forbidden response header names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Forbidden_response_header_name).

これは XMLHttpRequest でも同様のようです。

- [JQuery Ajax Request: Change User-Agent - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5771878/jquery-ajax-request-change-user-agent)
- [Chrome拡張でHTTPヘッダを改変 | 言葉の海のプログラマー](http://lostlinksearch.net/blog/2012/03/chrome%E6%8B%A1%E5%BC%B5%E3%81%A7http%E3%83%98%E3%83%83%E3%83%80%E3%82%92%E6%94%B9%E5%A4%89/)